# What the difference between SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL(django-social-auth) and AUTH_USER_MODEL(Django)?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-socialauth

A bit frustrated about this.

What the difference between those options?

Which I need to use to override default django user model?

What the value SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL has by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the default django user model use `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. To use django-social-auth with the new model point to it by using `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Both use `auth.User` by default.